# GitHub actions to copy files to GitHub Workspace

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a few steps to copy some folders from source code to GitHub WorkSpace as shown below. On running this build I see

> Warning: No files were found with the provided path: ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}. No artifacts will be uploaded.

I checked and confirmed that both folders are not empty. What am I missing?

```
   - name: copy arm templates
      run: Copy 'Infrastructure/' '${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/Infrastructure'
      shell: powershell
      
    - name: copy release management scripts
      run: Copy 'Scripts/' '${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/Scripts'
      shell: powershell
      
    - name: publish artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        path: ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}
        name: ${{ env.VERSION_MAJOR }}.${{ env.VERSION_MINOR }}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your syntax for using expressions and the GitHub actions context is wrong (reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions).

Use `${{ github.workspace }}` instead of `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}`

```
    - name: publish artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}
        name: ${{ env.VERSION_MAJOR }}.${{ env.VERSION_MINOR }}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Quick question - I only copied 2 folders to GitHub workspace. However I see the entire source code in the artifact. Why is that?

Comment: `github.workspace` is the default path for the checkout action. So your repository will be checked out to this path.

Comment: Makes sense. so, if I need to upload only specific folders/files to artifact, what should I do? Please let me know.

Comment: See https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#upload-using-multiple-paths-and-exclusions